# Как удалить плагин?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ide, archlinux

Хотел русифицировать eclipse. Установил babel, но после перезагрузки eclipse выдает ошибку:

> Возникла ошибка. Просмотрите файл протокола /home/andrey/Workspace/.metadata/.log.

Способ запуска через терминал с командой `eclipse -nl ru` не помогает — появляется та же ошибка. Подскажите как удалить этот плагин.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перезагрузка Eclipse с флагом -clean исправит проблему.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли! Теперь все в порядке)
Я уже выругал себя на тему зачем я это вообще сделал, ведь это такая глупая затея. А можно как то вообще этот плагин удалить, а то что я не доверяю ему (и назад инглишь вернуть)?

Comment: Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Installed Software tab > Uninstall...

Comment: Запускайте IDE  так eclipse.exe -nl en_US

или

Добавьте переменную -Duser.language=en в файл eclipse.ini под секцией VMArgs как описано ниже:
…
-vmargs
-Duser.language=en

Comment: Если вам помог ответ, поставьте галочку

Comment: Совет помог. Теперь снова на родном английском)
Галочку поставить не могу, т.к. не хватает рейтинга. Нужно галочку на вопросе получить, тогда и я смогу галочки ставить.

Comment: @Dmitry Petukhov, насчёт того совета: eclipse.exe в *nix-системе?